supervisor status is starting but running well
Not sure if anyone has experienced this before
I start Supervisor: sudo supervisorctl status
[program:catalogueproductslistener]
directory=/var/www/codemanual
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=catalogue_app.settings.production_settings
command=/var/www/venv/bin/python manage.py message_listener --settings=catalogue_app.settings.production_settings
user=mohammad_ayub
autostart=false
autorestart=false
startsecs=60
startretries=3
stdout_logfile=/data/logs/supervisor/catalogueproductslistener.log
stderr_logfile=/data/logs/supervisor/catalogueproductslistener_err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=20MB
stderr_logfile_backups=5
loglevel=debug

Supervisor status stays at STARTING, but the command looks to be running perfectly, in fact, it work better than if the status was RUNNING. By better I mean that it doesn't look t be consuming increasing amounts of memory, like it did when it was RUNNING
Supervisor log shows it is doing what I expect.
